# DOMDocument insertBefore error

Tags: domdocument

I'm trying to insert some elements before their parent element like this:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($this->_template);

    $xpath  = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $blockNodeList = $xpath->query('//block[@name="'.$name.'"]');
    foreach ($blockNodeList as $blockNode) {
        if ($blockNode->hasChildNodes()) {
            foreach ($blockNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
                if ($childNode->nodeName != '#text') {
                    $blockNode->insertBefore($childNode, $blockNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it only returns a error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert it into the parent element.

```
$blockNode->parentNode->insertBefore($childNode, $blockNode);
```

Comment: The solution above almost worked:

$blockNode->parentNode->insertBefore($childNode->cloneNode(true), $blockNode);

Thanks for your help!